# UITextView freeze content size

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview

I want to change UITextView's height dynamically but only up to `MAX_HEIGHT` value. 
I use code like this in `textViewDidChange` delegate:

```
CGSize contentSize = [_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(_textView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
CGFloat newHeight = ceilf(contentSize.height);
if (newHeight > MAX_HEIGHT)
{
    _textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    return;
}

CGFloat currentHeight = _textView.keepHeight.equal.value;
CGFloat delta = newHeight - currentHeight;

_textView.keepHeight.equal = KeepNone;
_textView.keepHeight.equal = KeepRequired(newHeight);
```

Initially I switch off scrolling with `_textView.scrollEnabled = NO`.

This works fine until it reaches `MAX_HEIGHT` and I turn scrolling on. It simply not scroll, not show new lines/letters. Nothing.

In debugger I see that content size always has height = `MAX_HEIGHT`, even if `sizeThatFits` show another value. Looks like it freeze. Also if I try to change value of content size inside my code, it returns back to `MAX_HEIGHT` in next delegate call.

Comment: Have you checked the value of 'newHeight'?

Comment: @AsifAsif yes, it grows up if I add more lines or tap more characters.